# add text on the edge of line in proof tree

Tags: forest, trees, logic, prooftrees

[image]

How can I do this in latex ?
This is what I've tried,

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
        [$(\lnot \,A \to (B \to \lnot C)$
            [$\lnot \, A$
            [$A$]
            ]
            [ $(B \to \lnot \,C)$
            [$B$]
            [$\lnot \, C$[$C$]]
            ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to here! You could use `prooftrees` as your tag suggests.

Comment: Thanks, then how would I achieve this in prooftrees?

Comment: You have unbalanced brackets in the first (non-)wff, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm obviously biased, but I'd use `prooftrees`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[tableaux]{prooftrees}
\forestset{
  my label/.style={
    edge label={node [midway, font=\scriptsize, left] {$#1$}}
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tableau}{not line numbering, single branches, not auto move}
  [(\lnot  A \to (B \to \lnot  C))
    [\lnot  A, my label=\to
      [A, my label=\lnot]
    ]
    [ (B \to \lnot C)
      [B, my label=\to]
      [\lnot  C[C, my label=\lnot]]
    ]
  ]
\end{tableau}
\end{document}
```

[image: tableau with <code>prooftrees</code>]

I've only used `standalone` for the example, but obviously you can use `amsart` or whatever you wish.

Comment: wowwww! Thanks !!!

Comment: @kratoooos You're welcome. It's all `forest` under the hood, of course. Do you know the LaTeX for Logicians site? https://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/trees/ covers setting tableaux.

Comment: No, but I will check it out. Thanks again!

Comment: hello, my complier says it does not recoginize ``not auto move'', do you have any idea ?

Comment: @kratoooos You probably have an outdated version of `prooftrees`. Current Texlive has the latest version. I'm not sure about MikTeX. Or you can get it from CTAN.